# "Operating System Not Found"

Tags: boot, partitioning, mbr

I did a bad format of my pc, I think I erased the mbr too. Everytime I turn on pc it shows me the message "No Operative System Found" .

I accessed to BIOS and changed booting option to read CD :

- If I insert XP Installation CD , it returns to me the message "Operating System Not Found"
- If I insert Xubuntu Installation CD it shows me Xubuntu menu , but is not able to install it or let me try live version , it only allow me doing a memory test

then I tried with GPARTED and it works , I formatted the HD and deallocated .

My question is :

- There is a way to install an OS ?

---

---

Now The situation is the follow :

[image]

I deleted partitions and created a new one in NTFS for xp , now this partition is ACTIVE , i have to chose any FLAG for this partition ?

---

---

These are my BIOS info

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 1) Formatting a harddisk will not delete the boot record. So unless you specifically erased that it should still be present. 
2) In your screenshot I do not see an **active** partition.
3) Why did you create /dev/sda5 at the beginning of the disk? I am not sure if windows likes to be installed in an extended partition.

Comment: @Hennes how can made /dev/sda2 active ? 

I have to delete /dev/sda5 ?

Comment: You did not specify which OS you are trying to install. If it is a linux then you can mark sda5 as active, format it (ext2|3|4,..) and install. For windows, create a primary partition of type 6 (NTFS) as the first partition on the disk. Since you currently only have room for 2MB you will either have to move or delete sda5.

Comment: @Hennes I edited the post with the actual situation

Comment: @Jon Skeet , I heard you're the best around , could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the HDD cables, whether it is loosen or not. 
If you think your Disk Sectors are corrupted then do as follow:
First create a partition with 100 or 500 MB and leave it. Then install the OS on the remaining partition.

Comment: it's a notebook pc , it doesn't allow me to install os

Comment: Ok. Using GParted, delete all the partitions available in your HDD. Create Partitions again and Install the OS

Comment: I edited the post with the actual situation

Comment: If you want to install Windows XP, delete the sda2 partition also. Insert XP bootable media, and during the setup process ,create the partitions and format it as NTFS. It will automatically makes it active.

Comment: it still says "Operating System Not Found"

Comment: it means it actually boots up through the HDD and not through the XP CD. Change the Boot sequence to CD. Double Check the BIOS settings are saved.

Comment: It is still setted

Comment: Make sure your XP CD is bootable. Put the CD in another PC and make sure it is working and bootable.
Try Installing OS with another HDD put into your notebook. If it works, your Disk is faulty.
This happens when,
The BIOS does not detect the hard disk. or
The hard disk is damaged

Comment: The BIOS detect HD , but I think mbr is corrupted or worse erased ... how could I solve ?

Comment: A missing or corrupt MBR should not be a problem as long as you boot from the windows installation DVD. Worst case boot from a windows 7 DVD, use SHIFT F10 to get a prompt and do a `diskpart clean`, reboot and install.

Comment: @Hennes Originally , on the machine windows vista was installed , windows xp installation dvd shows me the same message "Operating System Not Found" , so should I use windows 7 DVD ? 

I also tried to access to PQSERVICE partition , by pressing ALT+F10 and didn't worked , then I tried to flag it as BOOT partition but still didn't worked.

Then I tried installing Xubuntu by formatting a partition as EXT3 but Xubuntu hasn't been installed